# commandparameter in Datagrid & menucontext gives null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I stuck couple of hours in trying to get parameter from ContextMenu in Datagrid using MVVM.

The parameter comes from the CommandParameter is always null, out of set {Binding} but it's not what I want.

I new in WPF, so for me it is was not helpful to read answers from here and from others questions. It always remain null.
My code is below:

```
 <DataGrid  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="25,0,0,4" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="2"   Name="dgAltPart"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AltPartResult}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu >
                                <MenuItem Header="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.manufacturer}"
                                  Command="{Binding DeleteManufacturerCommand}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

                        <DataGrid.Columns>


                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer" Width="175"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer Part Number" Width="200"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer_pn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding price}"></DataGridTextColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>


                    </DataGrid>
```

And My ViewModel:

```
 private bool canExecute = true;
    public ICommand DeleteManufacturerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deleteManufacturerCommand == null)
            {
                _deleteManufacturerCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteManufacturer, param => this.canExecute);

            }
            return _deleteManufacturerCommand;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteManufacturer(object obj)
    {

    }
```

In DeleteManufacturer() I always get the obj with null.

so far tried with all kinds of relative source.
What do I miss?

Comment: You could bind the `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem` to a property in your ViewModel and then just pass that in your command parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define set `ContextMenu` property at row level, you could bind directly to the `DataContext` of each row. Try this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Margin="25,0,0,4" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="2"
                Name="dgAltPart"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AltPartResult}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.DeleteManufacturerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer" Width="175"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer Part Number" Width="200"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer_pn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding price}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="25,0,0,4" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="2"   Name="dgAltPart"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AltPartResult}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedManufacturer}"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu >
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedManufacturer}"
                              Command="{Binding DeleteManufacturerCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>


                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer" Width="175"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer Part Number" Width="200"  Binding="{Binding manufacturer_pn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding price}"></DataGridTextColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>


                </DataGrid>
```

and your ViewModel should have a property like this:

```
private Manufacturer selectedManufacturer;

    public Manufacturer SelectedManufacturer
    {
        get { return selectedManufacturer; }
        set { selectedManufacturer = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```